# Combinatorics problem about listing numbers $1,2,...n$

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the numbers $1,2,...,n$ be arranged as $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ so that for each $i > 1$ there is a $j < i$ such that $a_j = a_i \pm 1$?

For example, `1,2,3,4,5` and `4,3,5,2,1` are legal, but `1,3,5,2,4` is not as `1` comes before `2`, and `4,3,1,2,5` similarly is not.

I can see that `1` must either be the first number of the listing, or it must occur after `2` in any legal listing, but I can't see where to go from here.

Comment: Why is $43125$ not legal?

Comment: Because `1` is not the first number and also occurs before `2`.

Comment: @user167934 Neither of those conditions were part of the problem, so for what $i>1$ is the condition not true for 43125? (It is $i=3$, btw.)

Comment: In that listing we have $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 3, a_3 = 1, a_4 = 2, a_ 5 = 5$. Take $i=3 > 1$. Then then must be a $j < i = 3$ (so either $j=1$ or $2$) such that $a_j = a_i \pm 1 = a_3 \pm 1 = 1 \pm 1$. Since $0$ is not among the legal numbers, we need $a_j = 2$ for some $j < i = 3$.

Comment: This shows that `1` must either be the first number of the listing, or it must occur after `2` in any legal listing.

Comment: I'm not sure about the notation $a_j = a_i \pm 1$, could (should) we rather write it as $|a_j - a_i|=1$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the sequence from right to left helps. (Also, drawing how the numbers have to move (on, for example, $xy$ plane as $(x,y)=(i,a_i)$) may make it easier to understand the situation. )

- $a_n$ has to be either $1$ or $n$.
- $a_{n-1}$ has to be either the minimum number or the maximum number except $a_n$.
- $a_{n-2}$ has to be either the minimum number or the maximum number except $a_n,a_{n-1}$.
- $a_{n-3}$ has to be either the minimum number or the maximum number except $a_n,a_{n-1},a_{n-2}$, and so on.

These imply that the answer is $2^{n-1}$ ways.

**P.S.** Please see my comments below. They explain the situation.

Comment: Why must $a_n$ be either $1$ or $n$?

Comment: @Nishant: Because otherwise there is no such sequence. I really want to draw pictures to explain it... OK, let me explain it in words. Let $f(a_i)$ be the value of the biggest difference between $a_j$ for $1\le j\le i$. Then, we can see $f(a_i)\gt f(a_{i-1})$ holds for any $i\gt 1$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Nishant: Actually, $f(a_i)=f(a_{i-1})+1$ holds for any $i\gt 1$.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I see why $f(a_i)>f(a_{i-1})$. It's clearly true if $a_i>a_{i-1}$, but what about in the other case?

Comment: @Nishant: It's true for the other cases. Seeing what happens for the case $n=4,5$ may help. You'll see that $f(a_i)=f(a_{i-1})+1$ has to be held by the given condition. For example, for the case $n=4$, there are only $8$ ways: $1234, 2134,2314,2341,3214,3241,3421,4321$. Can you see that $f(a_i)=f(a_{i-1})+1$ holds for any $i\gt 1$ for every case? This fact leads that $a_n$ has to be either $1$ or $n$.

Comment: From the right?! Thanks! I didn't think of starting there! I think I can show your first point in a long winded way by showing that the numbers in any initial part of a legal listing must be an "interval of numbers" (not necessarily in order).

Comment: @user167934: 'interval of numbers'...Good point! That's what I want to say, indeed!

Comment: @mathlove 
I can see that it's true, but I can't quite understand WHY it's true, or why it must hold for larger $n$...

Comment: @Nishant: Well, I've said all I can say...Please draw pictures and see how the numbers move. The above comments will help. I'll tell you more if I find good hints to tell.